# How to use azure data factory migrate table in storage account, that have column is many type

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to use Data Factory to migrate data in the storage account, but data in the original table is a many type ex: some data in column `int`, `String`, `DateTime`.
When I use Data Factory I need to specify the data type, so how I can definite dynamic type and copy column. Because all data migrate parsed to `String` type, so how can I keep value type of column?
This my data in the original table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDEje.png)

Thanks for your help

Comment: you want to migrate the data between table storage?

Comment: yes, I want to migrate the table between 2 storage account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According my experience in Data factory, Data Factory can not help you keep value type of column in source table. You must specify the data type in sink dataset.

Copy Data:
[image]

As you have tried, if you didn't set the sink data type, the column type will passed  `String` in default.

I have an idea is that cope the data twice, each time copy the different entity column. The sink dataset support 'Merge' and 'Replace'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. But in the Storage Account, we can set 2 types in 1 column Ex: in "Name" column you can set `Int32` for some records. So, how can I keep 2 types in the "Name" column

Comment: Yeah, you can set different column type in table storage. I also added different column type in different entity, but when using Data Factory to copy data between two table storage,  copy active doesn't support us to do that.

Comment: It's also the same. I have an idea is that cope the data twice,  each time copy the different entity column. The sink dataset support 'Merge' and 'Replace'. You can try this.

Comment: @HungNguyenDuy nice！ I will update to my answer. If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I am understanding the question , but let me first put forward my understanding , you want to copy  a table lets say sourceT1 to SinkT1 , if that's the case you can always use the copy activity and then map the columns . When you map the columns it does set the data type also .

Comment: yes, but the column in sourceT1 I have 2 types
ex: a "value"  column has 2 types `Int64` and `String` 
how I can specify the data type of "source" and "sink" in JSON file